# np.unique blocks CPU with asyncio.to_thread

Tags: python, numpy, python-asyncio

I have set up the following test program (Python 3.9.5, numpy 1.20.2):

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

async def calculate():
    print("=== unique")
    await asyncio.to_thread(lambda: np.unique(np.ones((2000, 50000)), axis=0))
    print("=== sort")
    await asyncio.to_thread(lambda: np.sort(np.ones((2000, 50000)), axis=0))
    print("=== cumsum")
    await asyncio.to_thread(lambda: np.cumsum(np.ones((2000, 100000)), axis=0))

async def ping():
    while True:
        print("async", datetime.utcnow())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)

async def main():
    p1 = asyncio.create_task(ping())
    c = asyncio.create_task(calculate())
    await asyncio.wait([p1, c], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    p1.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is as follows:

```
async 2021-05-21 13:20:16.308948
=== unique
async 2021-05-21 13:20:16.531135
async 2021-05-21 13:20:40.142323
=== sort
async 2021-05-21 13:20:40.343306
async 2021-05-21 13:20:40.543658
async 2021-05-21 13:20:40.743989
async 2021-05-21 13:20:40.944312
async 2021-05-21 13:20:41.144664
async 2021-05-21 13:20:41.345007
=== cumsum
async 2021-05-21 13:20:41.545523
async 2021-05-21 13:20:41.745901
async 2021-05-21 13:20:41.946271
async 2021-05-21 13:20:42.146651
async 2021-05-21 13:20:42.347021
async 2021-05-21 13:20:42.547396
```

It is evident that `np.unique` takes ~23 seconds, and does not ever get interrupted the way it happens with `np.cumsum` and `np.sort`.

If my understanding of `asyncio.to_thread` and GIL is correct, anything that runs in a thread should be periodically interrupted to enable at least some degree of multitasking with threaded programs. This is supported by the behavior of `np.sort` and `np.cumsum`. What happens in `np.unique` that prevents that thread from being interrupted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this was a tricky one ;-)

The problem is that the GIL is not actually released in the `np.unique` call. The reason is the `axis=0` parameter (you can verify that without it the call to `np.unique` releases GIL and is interleaved with the `ping` call).

**TLDR**; The semantics of `axis` argument is different for `np.sort/cumsum` and `np.unique` calls: while for `np.sort/cumsum` the operation is performed vectorized "in" that axis (i.e., sorting several arrays independently), the `np.unique` is performed on slices "along" that axis, and these slices are non-trivial data types, hence they require Python methods.

With the `axis=0`, what numpy does is that it "slices" the array in the first axis, creating a `ndarray` with shape `(2000, 1)`, each element being an "n-tuple of values" (its dtype is an array of dtypes of the individual elements); this happens at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7de0fa959e476900725d8a654775e0a38745de08/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L282-L294 .

Then a `ndarray.sort` method is called at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7de0fa959e476900725d8a654775e0a38745de08/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L333. That in the end calls https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7de0fa959e476900725d8a654775e0a38745de08/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1236, which tries to release GIL at line https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7de0fa959e476900725d8a654775e0a38745de08/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L979 , whose definition is at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7de0fa959e476900725d8a654775e0a38745de08/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L1004-L1006 -- so the GIL is released only if the type does not state `NPY_NEEDS_PYAPI`. However, given that the individual array elements are at this point nontrivial types, I assume they state `NPY_NEEDS_PYAPI` (I would expect for example comparisons to go through Python), and the GIL is not released.

Cheers.

Comment: Wow! I'd expect that the GIL would be preempted from the thread after some quantum of time though - there are mentions of 15ms time slicing. This doesn't work with `.sort()` on Python lists, because it's a single instruction in the bytecode. Is the numpy sort a similar case?

Comment: The numpy sort is an extension method (a C++ method), so from a Python interpreter's point of view it is a single instruction. If I understand the GIL implementation (see docs at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/ceval_gil.h), it is a form of cooperative multitasking, not pre-emptive multitasking, so if a thread does not release GIL by itself, it will not be forced to give it up.

Comment: You are right, preemption is not the correct word here :) If calling the extension method is in fact a single instruction, then I understand there's nothing the Python interpreter can do if that method doesn't release the GIL. Thank you for the thorough answer!